# Script that will grab random images from various tags on tumblr

Tags: javascript, php, tumblr

I want to have a webpage that grabs random images from specified tags on tumblr. I know that there's a script on stackoverflow that does that with one blog, but I need something that will grab images from **tags**. Is it even possible to create?

Comment: Yes it is possible. So start implementing it and if you encounter any problems we will help you :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. We are here to help solve issues **not** write code for you. Please read: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: I haven't asked for the final code, I'm asking if it's possible to do. "Is it even possible to create?" My question has been answered, it can be closed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here
https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged-method
You can use for example:

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=lol&api_key=blablab
```

to get a json of some pictures, then shuffle the array with sonething like this

[How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)